# If I scp a file through an intermediate server, is the file stored temporarily on the server?

Tags: ssh, security, encryption, scp, ssh-tunnel

*For the sake of simplicity (I find it easier to remember names than arbitrary letters), I will dispense with letters and use names to refer to the machines in this scenario.*

Say I have two machines, `applejack` and `pinkie-pie`, each on their own separate LANs and not in the same physical location. I also have a server, `cadance`, with a direct Internet-facing connection. I want to copy a file from `applejack` to `pinkie-pie`, so to avoid dealing with port forwarding and such, I set up an ssh tunnel from `pinkie-pie` to `cadance` (`ssh -R` etc `cadance`). Now I can connect to `pinkie-pie` from anywhere, by connecting to `cadance` and specifying an alternate port to use. I can also easily copy files to `pinkie-pie` with `scp -P $that_port $some_file cadance:$some_path`.

My understanding of how it works is this:

1. A secure connection is made from `applejack` to `cadance`
2. I am authenticated to `cadance`
3. A secure connection is made from `applejack` to `pinkie-pie` that spans the existing reverse tunnel and the new connection from step 1.
4. I am authenticated to `pinkie-pie`
5. Files are copied directly from `applejack` to `pinkie-pie` over this connection.

Am I correct here? How secure is this approach?

If I'm wrong…are files copied this way decrypted at `cadance` before being passed on to `pinkie-pie`? Is there a possibility that traces of unencrypted data could remain on `cadance`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your understanding is not completely right. If I understood correctly, you are doing that last command (`scp -P $that_port $some_file cadance:$some_path`) from `applejack`. In that case, you are not authenticating to `cadance` (step 2), but merely connecting to the reverse tunnel to `pinkie-pie`.

The secure connection goes directly from `applejack` to `pinkie-pie`; there is no secure connection between `applejack` and `cadance` (step 1). `cadance` is in principle able to read the cleartext that passes over the reverse tunnel, but that cleartext in itself is another encrypted channel, so it'd have to break it.

So you have an end-to-end encrypted channel between `applejack` and `pinkie-pie`, just as if you had connected them directly. The reverse tunnel just serves as a convoluted way of routing the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

In a tunnel of any sort there will be temporary holding of data, thats where data can be intercepted, but if the intermidiate server is picking up encrypted data and sending it on then it shouldnt be able to do anything with it. So yes there is a point where the middle man gets the data because otherwise he wouldnt be a middle man.

Comment: Just to note: Whilst someone could pretend to be `cadence` with an open port for you to connect to, they wouldn't have the signature for `pinkie-pie` and so the SSL library ought to warn you about the 'bad things' that are happening.